# python reduce: find total size of all lists inside list of tuples

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

my data structure looks as below

```
itemsData = [('data1', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('data2', [1, 2]), ('data3', [1, 2, 3])]
```

I want to find total number of items in the list of tuples above. For above example, len([1,2,3,4] + len([1,2]) + len([1,2,3]) = 9

```
reduce(lambda x,y: len(x[1]) + len(y[1]), itemsData )
```

error i get is

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will explain why your code does not work

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce,

> The left argument, x, is the accumulated value and the right argument, y, is the update value from the iterable

So in the first iteration, your code
`len(x[1]) + len(y[1])` works since `x=('data1', [1, 2, 3, 4])`, `y=('data2', [1, 2])`, and the result is `6`,

However in the second iteration, you get `x=6`, `y=('data3', [1, 2, 3])]`,
so `len(x[1])` is invalid.

The correct code using reduce, is

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+len(y[1]), itemsData, 0)
```

This works since

```
1st iteration ... x = 0, y = ('data1', [1, 2, 3, 4]), result = 4
2nd iteration ... x = 4, y = ('data2', [1, 2]), result = 6
3rd iteration ... x = 6, y = ('data3', [1, 2, 3]), result = 9
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply try:

```
sum([len(elem[1]) for elem in itemsData])
```

E.g.

```
>>> itemsData = [('data1', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('data2', [1, 2]), ('data3', [1, 2, 3])]
>>> sum([len(elem[1]) for elem in itemsData])
9
```

Comment: There is no need to construct an intermediate list of the lengths. Consider "sum(len(x[1]) for x in xs)".